# Optional vs obligatory back shifting

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Consider two sentences - 
1) I didn't know that X **is** a Russian.
2) I didn't know that X **was** a Russian.

My question is, under the condition that X is still Russian, can sentence 1) be used ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you think it couldn't be used?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legitimate to say "I didn't know that X is a Russian" in the proper context.  For instance, the following dialog:

> X just came back from visiting his family in Moscow.
>
> I didn't know that X is a Russian.

X is (apparently) a Russian at the present moment.  Up until this moment you did not know this.

Comment: This is a good example.

Comment: And what would you say about - I didn't know + present perfect ? Is this usage possible under the condition that the situation is still relevant ?

Answer (score -2):

Not really. IMO, 1 fails the tradition of the English language, which requires **tense consistency**, and that is thoroughly confirmed by Google Books:

["didn't know he is a"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22didn%27t%20know%20that%20%20he%20is%20a%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22didn%27t%20know%20he%20is%20a%22)
About **29** results

["**didn't** know he **was** a"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22didn%27t%20know%20that%20%20he%20is%20a%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22didn%27t%20know%20he%20was%20a%22)
About **509,000** results

Then, what does "Russian" mean in your context?

"Russian born/by birth"? That never changes.

"Russian citizen/national"? That can change.

Anyway, the point is **why would they have been concerned in say 1990 about what he is in say 2015**? Except if they went on a time travel :-)

Comment: Your Google results confirm nothing.